# How to pass arguments to the function inside atexit(), C

Tags: c

I have this function that does some free and unregs from a network:

```
void UNREG_on_exit(COT_arguments args, Node_Information *node)
```

I'm trying to make it be called whenever I'm exiting the program (even with Ctrl+C)

The problem is how do I pass the arguments?
Never done a function pointer and can't really find an answer.

Currently I have:

```
void UNREG_on_exit(args, &node); // This is how you make the pointer?
atexit(UNREG_on_exit);

// or //

atexit((void) {
    UNREG_on_exit(args, &node); // Or like this?
});
```

I have no idea, and both of them give me an error.

"expected an identifier", a red line under the argument

Addicional Info:

```
typedef struct Node_Information
{
    int id;
    int net;
    Backup bck;
    Extern ext;
    Intern *intern_list;
    int InNetword;
    int debug_mode;
    int IsREGED;
    int fd;
    Table *table_list;
    StringList *contents_list;
    PendingConnections *pending_connections_list;
    QueryList *query_list;

} Node_Information;

typedef struct COT_arguments
{
    char *IP;
    int TCP;
    char *reg_IP;
    int reg_UDP;
} COT_arguments;
```

Comment: Both of them give you *what* error?

Comment: Could you share the exact error? So that people won't guess what error it gave.

Comment: How/where are `args` and `node` defined?

Comment: expected an identifier, a red line under the argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have this function that does some free and unregs from a network:
>
> ```
> void UNREG_on_exit(COT_arguments args, Node_Information *node)
> ```
>
> I'm trying to make it be called whenever I'm exiting the program (even with Ctrl+C)

**Frame challenge**: why?

Especially why worry about freeing allocated memory at program exit, as the system will release that whether you explicitly free it or not.  It will also close the process's open files, including network connections.  That may not yield a clean application-level disconnect from remote network services, but any such services need to be robust against such events anyway.

I've written a lot of software, and I don't recall ever registering an exit handler.  I arrange for resources to be cleaned up at appropriate points as the program progresses, and for any final cleanup to be performed explicitly at normal termination.  This is clearer and less mysterious than using exit handlers.  I rarely see a need to make special provisions to handle abnormal termination, and it is not possible to handle *all* abnormal terminations.  Even if there were not fatal signals that cannot be caught or handled, there is no software-level protection available from abrupt power loss or catastrophic hardware failure.

But if you insist on **trying to handle abnormal termination**, then you're going to need to work harder.  The exit handlers registered by standard `atexit()` and GNU-specific `on_exit()` run at *normal* program termination, which means when the `exit()` function is called or the initial call to `main()` returns.  They do not run when the process is killed by a signal (which is the kind of termnination Ctrl+C produces), or when it terminates because of a call to `_exit()` or `_Exit()`, or when it stops running without terminating, such as by calling `execve()`.

You can probably avoid calling `_Exit()` and other problematic functions, but to engage cleanup upon receiving a signal, you will need to register a signal handler for *all* the signals whose default disposition is to terminate the program.  Or for those that can be caught at all, at least, which is not all of them.  Moreover, signal handlers may call only async-signal-safe functions, lest they introduce undefined behavior.  I'm not sure what your "unregs" entail, so perhaps these would be ok, but `free()` is not async-signal-safe.  Nor is `exit()`, lest you think you could call that to convert abnormal termination into normal termination.

As for the specifics of **using `atexit()`** to handle the normal-termination case, the signature of `atexit()` is

```
int atexit(void (*function)(void));
```

The function-pointer argument is thus expected to point to a function that has no parameters and does not return anything, and that's how it will be called.  Any data that such a function works on must be either globally scoped (global variables, environment variables, the process's own PID, ...) or discoverable by that function (time of day, files in some well-known directory, ...).  Example:

```
static void *allocated;

static void cleanup_handler(void) {
    free(allocated);
}

int main(void) {
    at_exit(cleanup_handler);
    // ...
}
```

Your particular C implementation may provide other alternatives, such as the *GNU-specific* `on_exit()`.  Details of these will vary.  **`on_exit()` itself** permits you to register a data pointer along with the callback pointer, to be passed to the function when it is called.  This is how you would provide data to that function, but note that the data must have static storage duration, else its lifetime will have already ended when the exit handler is called.  Example:

```
struct data_to_clean_up {
    void *allocated;
    // ...
} loose_ends;

void cleanup_handler(int status, void *data) {
    struct data_to_clean_up *loose_ends = (struct data_to_clean_up *) data;
    free(loose_ends->allocated);
    // ...
}

int main(void) {
    on_exit(cleanup_handler, &loose_ends);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: university be like why not?

Comment: @Filipe, because *you can't*, for one, as this answer already explains.  And because it doesn't make much sense to try to ensure cleanup in abnormal termination cases, because they are, after all, abnormal.  With respect to memory, because it is simpler to write and maintain code that relies on the system for some cleanup, and there is no operational downside to this.

Answer (score 6):

A function registered by `atexit` cannot take parameters.  It's signature is required to be  `void (*)(void)`, i.e. a function that returns nothing and takes no parameters.

You'll need to use global variables that get set elsewhere in your program that the function can use.

Answer (score 4):

`atexit` doesn't support functions taking parameters, so you can neither register such a function with it nor pass any parameters to that function. You have to pass a function pointer of type `void(*)(void)` - taking no parameters, returning no value.

So that part has to be handled through some other means, for example by using a file scope variable. As with any use of "callback functions" like this, be careful to not use any pointers to local data, but only to static storage or dynamically allocated memory.

Also note that `atexit` calls functions in reverse order like a FIFO - that is, the function registred last will get executed first.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char* str1;
static char* str2;

void this_is_the_end1 (void) { puts(str1); }
void this_is_the_end2 (void) { puts(str2); }

int main (void)
{
  str1 = "The end of everything that stands";
  atexit(this_is_the_end1);
  str2 = "The end of our elaborate plans";
  atexit(this_is_the_end2);

  puts("This is the end, beautiful friend");
  puts("This is the end, my only friend");
}
```

Output order is guaranteed by ISO C:

```
This is the end, beautiful friend
This is the end, my only friend
The end of our elaborate plans
The end of everything that stands
```

Answer (score 2):

[`on_exit(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/on_exit.3.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Except this is non-portable Unix gunk. It ain't even part of POSIX. There's no indication that the OP is using *nix.

Comment: This is GNU-specific.